# How to use devise sign_in helper in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have seen solutions to this but none seem to fit what I am trying to do here. I have this code as an admin and I would like to have a link next to each user's name to sign in as that user.

```
<ol>
    <% User.all.each do |u| %>
    <li>
        <%= u.username %>
        [enter link_to sign in @u or something]
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ol>
```

Comment: simple just use devise `sign_in`  method

Comment: I'm slightly new at this. How would you do this, because I don't want to use a form which would require a password and email. I just want a link to switch users. (without any gems)

Comment: are you using devise right?

Comment: can you tell me what errors are you facing?

Comment: Yes, I am using devise. I don't have any errors because I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: its simple just you need to create one controller method for routes and create action in this controller and use devise sign_in_and_redirect method in this action  it is good if you show me code or git repo

Comment: I created a "pages" controller with adminhome.html.erb The route is "get 'pages/adminhome'". An admin is expressed as a boolean attribute for the User model.

Comment: how can i identify user is logged in at dashboard?

Comment: its solved man should i  make commit on github

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you just paste the code in an answer?

Comment: can you please check my answer and inform me if you have any issues

Comment: Thank you so much! This will really come in handy :)

Comment: Your welcome man happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in this case devise `sign_in` helper method is useful but we are not able to use it in view so we have to make `routes` which internally  `devise` `sign_in` method for achieving this you have to follow below steps

#### config/routes.rb

```
get "sign/:id"=>"pages#sign",as:'user_sign'
```

add above code in routes

than create `sign` action in controler

#### app/controllers/pages_controller.rb

```
def sign
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    sign_in_and_redirect(user)
end
```

finally make changes in view so all of your code will work fine

```
  <li>
    <%= u.username %>
    <a href="/users/<%= u.id %>">Prof.</a>
    <img width="50" src="<%= u.profilepic %>">
    <%= link_to "sign in",user_sign_path(u.id)%>
  </li>
```

i hope its work for you

its just tweak to call `sign_in` method from view

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this https://github.com/flyerhzm/switch_user

Warning

This feature should be used with extreme caution because of the security implications. This is especially true in a production environment.

Comment: My app will be in production soon, I don't think this will work sadly

Comment: @MateoC why not? You can use in prod, as soon as you address the security implications and ensure that only admins can do that. Tests covering that are essential imo.